# get data from closed workbook with getopenfilename and vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, getopenfilename

I would like to pull data from a closed worksheet using GetOpenFileName and VLOOKUP, but I am new to VBA and unfamiliar with the syntax.

I keep hitting an "Automation error" or "Object error" that doesn't specify what is wrong. 
I believe my range arg in VLOOKUP is incorrect but am not sure what it should be.
Can anyone help me please?

```
Sub GetAmazonInventory()

Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Application.GetOpenFilename, ReadOnly:=True)
wbk.Activate

Dim shtName As String
shtName = wbk.Worksheets(1).Name

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = wbk.Worksheets(shtName)

wbk.Close

ActiveCell.Value = Application.IfError(Application.VLookup(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -12), sh.Range("A2:F900"), 5, False), 20)

End Sub
```

Comment: Just to clarify - you closed the workbook with `wbk.Close` and want to know why your `sh.Range("A2:F900")` isn't working when `sh` is referring to the closed workbook?

Comment: @K.Davis I'm pretty new to VBA :( Is it impossible to grab the data when the wbk is closed? If I keep it open, I am not sure how to reference the ActiveCell and get the first Arg for the VLookUp function.

Comment: You can set a variable to the active cell first. I will add an answer

Answer (score 2):

The reason for your error is that you closed the workbook, and are still attempting to pull a range from that closed workbook.

If you are wanting to keep the new workbook open but use the original `ActiveCell`'s range, then you can just create a variable for that cell.

```
Sub GetAmazonInventory()

    ' Set a reference to your 'Active Cell'
    Dim myCell As Range
    Set myCell = ActiveCell

    Dim wbk As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Application.GetOpenFilename, ReadOnly:=True)
    Set ws = wbk.Worksheets(1)

    myCell.Value = Application.IfError(Application.VLookup(myCell.Offset(0, -12), _
            ws.Range("A2:F900"), 5, False), 20)

    wbk.Close

End Sub
```

> **Side Note:** You do not need to get the worksheet's name first just to set the worksheet. So I removed that.
>
> I would also add some validation that the activecell is at least in the correct column / row. If your active cell should always be in column B for example, then something like:
>
> ```
> If myCell.Column <> 2 then
>     Msgbox "ActiveCell is not in the correct column. Please reselect!"
>     Exit Sub
> End If
> ```

Comment: Looks like ActiveCell has to be in column M or right of column M (i.e. 13th column or higher).

Comment: True. I just did it because for many it's easier to know that `B = 2` more than `M = 13` xD

Answer (score 1):

You can reference a closed workbook with a VLOOKUP formula on the worksheet. You will need to store a string representing a complete qualified path to the range before closing the workbook.

Since you've given no indication what ActiveCell is and use Offset to

```
Sub GetAmazonInventory()

    Dim wbk As Workbook, addr as string

    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Application.GetOpenFilename, ReadOnly:=True)
    addr = wbk.Worksheets(1).Range("A2:F900").address(external:=true)
    wbk.Close

    ActiveCell.formula = "=iferror(vLookup(" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, -12).address(0, 0) & _
                           ", " & addr & ", 5, False), 20)"

End Sub
```